# VueJS SPA freezing\lagging

Tags: vue.js

Just made a copy of one SPA project built on Laravel+VueJS for debugging and testing. DBs are identical (dump from production).
Everything works but sometimes (while working with complex components) the whole tab with SPA freezes for 4-7 seconds. Original project works fine. No lags, no freezes. Also the dumped DB works a little bit slower than the original, but does it matter?

The question is what actually could go wrong here?

Comment: It happens every time api call responded to axios.

Comment: This does not seem like a coding bug. Looks like some architecture stuff. Not right here at stackoverflow imho

Comment: @jdickel solved by removing Laravel debugbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching off laravel debugbar